# Add multiple input field dynamically in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have is a div that contains three input elements and a remove button. what is required is when the user clicks on the add button it will add this div dynamically and when the user clicks on the remove button it will remove this div. I was able to add one input element (without div container) dynamically with the following method.

- create an array in the state variable.
- assign a name to the dynamic input field with the help of array indexing like name0, name1

How can I do with these many input fields? The problem grows further when I create this whole div as a separate component. I am using a class-based component.

```
handleChange=(event) =>
  {
    this.setState({[event.target.name]:event.target.values});
  }

render()
  {
    return(
      <div className="row">
        <button type="button" onClick={this.addElement}>Add</button>
        <div className="col-md-12 form-group">
          <input type="text" className="form-control" name="name" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleChange} />
          <input type="text" className="form-control" name="email" value={this.state.email} onChange={this.handleChange} />
          <input type="text" className="form-control" name="phone" value={this.state.phone} onChange={this.state.phone} />
          <button type="button" onClick={this.removeElement}>Remove</button>
        </div> 
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Comment: Are you trying to add/remove the `div`, or add/remove inputs? You question jumps between the two scenarios. If it's inputs how do you determine what _type_ of input it is before you add it?

Comment: this might be helpful for u:https://bapunawarsaddam.medium.com/add-and-remove-form-fields-dynamically-using-react-and-react-hooks-3b033c3c0bf5

Comment: @Andy I am trying to add a div that contains the inputs. type of input is static and does not change.

Comment: @Pranaykumar you could use an array/object and map it to return the required component. and use a state to push to array and it will render the component for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would approach this from a configuration angle as it's a little more scalable. If you want to eventually change across to something like Formik or React Form, it makes the move a little easier.

Have an array of objects that you want to turn into input fields. Your main component should maintain state whether the `<Form />` component is showing, and if it's visible pass in the config and any relevant handlers.

Your form component should maintain state for the inputs, and when you submit it, passes up the completed state to the parent.

```js
const { Component } = React;

class Example extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super();

    // The only state in the main component
    // is whether the form is visible or not
    this.state = { visible: false };
  }

  addForm = () => {
    this.setState({ visible: true });
  }

  removeForm = () => {
    this.setState({ visible: false });
  }

  handleSubmit = (form) => {
    console.log(form);
  }

  render() {
    
    const { visible } = this.state;
    const { config } = this.props;
    
    return (

      <div>
        <button
          type="button"
          onClick={this.addForm}
        >Add form
        </button>

        {visible && (
          <Form
            config={config}
            handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
            handleClose={this.removeForm}
          />
        )}

      </div>
    );
  
  }

};

class Form extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.state = props.config.reduce((acc, c) => {
      return { ...acc, [c.name]: '' };
    }, {});
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    this.setState({ [name]: value });
  }

  handleSubmit = () => {
    this.props.handleSubmit(this.state);
  }

  render() {

    const { name, email, phone } = this.state;
    const { handleClose, config } = this.props;
        
    return (
      
      <div onChange={this.handleChange}>
        
        {config.map(input => {
          const { id, name, type, required } = input;
          return (
            <div>
              <label>{name}</label>
              <input key={id} name={name} type={type} required={required} />
            </div>
          )
        })}
        
        <button type="button" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Submit form</button>
        
        <button type="button" onClick={handleClose}>Remove form</button>
      
      </div>
    
    );
  
  }

}

const config = [
  { id: 1, name: 'name', type: 'text', required: true },
  { id: 2, name: 'email', type: 'email', required: true },
  { id: 3, name: 'phone', type: 'phone', required: true }
];


ReactDOM.render(
  <Example config={config} />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```css
input { display: block; }
label { text-transform: capitalize; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this would be help for your question.
I made a child component which have three input tags.

```
// parent component
import React, { Component } from "react";
import TextField from "./TextField";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      users: [
        {
          key: Date.now(),
          name: "",
          email: "",
          phone: ""
        }
      ]
    };
  }

  onChange = (inputUser) => {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      const newUsers = prevState.users.map((element) => {
        if (element.key === inputUser.key) return inputUser;
        return element;
      });
      return { users: newUsers };
    });
  };

  addElement = () => {
    const { name, email, phone } = this.state;
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      users: prevState.users.concat({
        key: Date.now(),
        name,
        email,
        phone
      })
    }));
  };

  removeElement = (id) => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      users: prevState.users.filter((user) => user.key !== id)
    }));
  };

  render() {
    const { users } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="row">
        <button type="button" onClick={this.addElement}>
          Add
        </button>
        <div className="col-md-12 form-group">
          {users.map((user) => (
            <React.Fragment key={user.key}>
              <TextField
                value={user}
                onChange={(inputUser) => this.onChange(inputUser)}
              />
              <button
                type="button"
                onClick={() => this.removeElement(user.key)}
                disabled={users.length <= 1}
              >
                Remove
              </button>
            </React.Fragment>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

```
// child component
import { Component } from "react";

class TextField extends Component {
  handleChange = (ev) => {
    const { name, value } = ev.target;
    this.props.onChange({
      ...this.props.value,
      [name]: value
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { value: user } = this.props;
    return (
      <>
        <input
          className="form-control"
          name="name"
          value={user.name}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          placeholder="name"
          type="text"
        />
        <input
          className="form-control"
          name="email"
          value={user.email}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          placeholder="email"
          type="text"
        />
        <input
          className="form-control"
          name="phone"
          value={user.phone}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          placeholder="phone"
          type="text"
        />
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default TextField;
```

You can also check the code in codesandbox link below.
https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-heisenberg-xzchm

Answer (score 0):

It was a little difficult to write down every detail of how to generate what you want. So I find it much easier to ready a `stackblitz` link for you to see how is it going to do this and the link is ready below:

[generating a dynamic div adding and removing by handling inputs state value](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kp2syr?file=src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

```js
const { Component } = React;

class Example extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super();

    // The only state in the main component
    // is whether the form is visible or not
    this.state = { visible: false };
  }

  addForm = () => {
    this.setState({ visible: true });
  }

  removeForm = () => {
    this.setState({ visible: false });
  }

  handleSubmit = (form) => {
    console.log(form);
  }

  render() {
    
    const { visible } = this.state;
    const { config } = this.props;
    
    return (

      <div>
        <button
          type="button"
          onClick={this.addForm}
        >Add form
        </button>

        {visible && (
          <Form
            config={config}
            handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
            handleClose={this.removeForm}
          />
        )}

      </div>
    );
  
  }

};

class Form extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.state = props.config.reduce((acc, c) => {
      return { ...acc, [c.name]: '' };
    }, {});
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    this.setState({ [name]: value });
  }

  handleSubmit = () => {
    this.props.handleSubmit(this.state);
  }

  render() {

    const { name, email, phone } = this.state;
    const { handleClose, config } = this.props;
        
    return (
      
      <div onChange={this.handleChange}>
        
        {config.map(input => {
          const { id, name, type, required } = input;
          return (
            <div>
              <label>{name}</label>
              <input key={id} name={name} type={type} required={required} />
            </div>
          )
        })}
        
        <button type="button" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Submit form</button>
        
        <button type="button" onClick={handleClose}>Remove form</button>
      
      </div>
    
    );
  
  }

}

const config = [
  { id: 1, name: 'name', type: 'text', required: true },
  { id: 2, name: 'email', type: 'email', required: true },
  { id: 3, name: 'phone', type: 'phone', required: true }
];


ReactDOM.render(
  <Example config={config} />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```css
input { display: block; }
label { text-transform: capitalize; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```